# Define header CSS class if menu items have children

Tags: templates, menu, submenu

I am using two menu modules to display parent and children items in different locations in the website header. The simplified code below shows how it is written in **index.php**.

I am needing to check to see if a menu item has children. If it does, the following class `has-nested-nav` should be added to the `<header>` div. This class will adjust the bottom padding on the header depending on if the nested nav module is displayed.

I have tested the code, but it does not yield the results I am needing. Please advise on what should be changed to get the code working.

Cheers.

**Template HTML**

```
<header class="**Add has-nested-nav class here**">
    <!-- Parent menu items -->
    <section>
    <?php if($this->countModules('global-navigation')): ?>
        <jdoc:include type="modules" name="global-navigation" />
    <?php endif; ?>
    </section>

    <!-- Children menu items -->
    <section>
    <?php if($this->countModules('global-nested-navigation')): ?>
        <jdoc:include type="modules" name="global-nested-navigation" />
    <?php endif; ?>
    </section>
</header>
```

**Template includes/helper.php file**

```
$hasParent = $menu->getItem( $menu->getActive()->parent_id );
if ($hasParent == 1) {
    $hasNestedNav = true;
} else {
    $hasNestedNav = false;
}

$mrwcNavClass = '';
if ($hasNestedNav) {
    $mrwcNavClass .= ' has-nested-nav';
}

if (!defined( 'MRWC_NAV_CLASS' )) {
    define( 'MRWC_NAV_CLASS', $mrwcNavClass);
}
```

**Current Code - Not working**

```
$active = $menu->getActive();
// $childCount = count($menu->getItems('parent_id', $active->id));
$children = $menu->getItems('parent_id', $active->id);
$visibleChildren = array_filter($children, function($child) {
    return ($child->getParams('menu_show', 1) === 1);
});

$childCount = count($visibleChildren);
if ($childCount == 1) {
    $hasNestedNav = true;
} else {
    $hasNestedNav = false;
}
```

**$active menu item dump**

```
object(Joomla\CMS\Menu\MenuItem)[699]
public 'id' => string '122' (length=3)
public 'menutype' => string 'global-navigation' (length=17)
public 'title' => string 'Education' (length=9)
public 'alias' => string 'education' (length=9)
public 'note' => string '' (length=0)
public 'route' => string 'education' (length=9)
public 'link' => string 'index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=2' (length=46)
public 'type' => string 'component' (length=9)
public 'level' => string '1' (length=1)
public 'language' => string '*' (length=1)
public 'browserNav' => string '0' (length=1)
public 'access' => string '1' (length=1)
protected 'params' => 
  object(Joomla\Registry\Registry)[913]
  protected 'data' => 
    object(stdClass)[915]
      public 'show_title' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'link_titles' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'show_intro' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'info_block_position' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'info_block_show_title' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'show_category' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'link_category' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'show_parent_category' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'link_parent_category' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'show_associations' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'show_author' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'link_author' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'show_create_date' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'show_modify_date' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'show_publish_date' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'show_item_navigation' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'show_vote' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'show_icons' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'show_print_icon' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'show_email_icon' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'show_hits' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'show_tags' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'show_noauth' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'urls_position' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'menu-anchor_title' => string 'Education' (length=9)
      public 'menu-anchor_css' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'menu_image' => string 'images/media/images/svg/nav-current-marker.svg' (length=46)
      public 'menu_image_css' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'menu_text' => int 1
      public 'menu_show' => int 1
      public 'page_title' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'show_page_heading' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'page_heading' => string 'Education' (length=9)
      public 'pageclass_sfx' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'menu-meta_description' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'menu-meta_keywords' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'robots' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'secure' => int 0
  protected 'initialized' => boolean true
  public 'separator' => string '.' (length=1)
  public 'home' => string '0' (length=1)
  public 'img' => string ' ' (length=1)
  public 'template_style_id' => string '0' (length=1)
  public 'component_id' => string '22' (length=2)
  public 'parent_id' => string '1' (length=1)
  public 'component' => string 'com_content' (length=11)
  public 'tree' => 
      array (size=1)
      0 => string '122' (length=3)
      public 'query' => 
          array (size=3)
          'option' => string 'com_content' (length=11)
          'view' => string 'article' (length=7)
          'id' => string '2' (length=1)
```

**$children menu items dump**

```
array (size=2)
0 => 
    object(Joomla\CMS\Menu\MenuItem)[726]
    public 'id' => string '1544' (length=4)
    public 'menutype' => string 'global-navigation' (length=17)
    public 'title' => string 'Classrooms' (length=10)
    public 'alias' => string 'classroom' (length=9)
    public 'note' => string '' (length=0)
    public 'route' => string 'education/classroom' (length=19)
    public 'link' => string 'index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=261' (length=48)
    public 'type' => string 'component' (length=9)
    public 'level' => string '2' (length=1)
    public 'language' => string '*' (length=1)
    public 'browserNav' => string '0' (length=1)
    public 'access' => string '1' (length=1)
    protected 'params' => 
        object(Joomla\Registry\Registry)[1490]
        protected 'data' => 
            object(stdClass)[1492]
            ...
            protected 'initialized' => boolean true
            public 'separator' => string '.' (length=1)
            public 'home' => string '0' (length=1)
            public 'img' => string ' ' (length=1)
            public 'template_style_id' => string '0' (length=1)
            public 'component_id' => string '22' (length=2)
            public 'parent_id' => string '122' (length=3)
            public 'component' => string 'com_content' (length=11)
            public 'tree' => 
                array (size=2)
                0 => string '122' (length=3)
                1 => string '1544' (length=4)
            public 'query' => 
                array (size=3)
                'option' => string 'com_content' (length=11)
                'view' => string 'article' (length=7)
                'id' => string '261' (length=3)
   1 => 
      object(Joomla\CMS\Menu\MenuItem)[725]
      public 'id' => string '1545' (length=4)
      public 'menutype' => string 'global-navigation' (length=17)
      public 'title' => string 'In The Community' (length=16)
      public 'alias' => string 'community' (length=9)
      public 'note' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'route' => string 'education/community' (length=19)
      public 'link' => string 'index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=262' (length=48)
      public 'type' => string 'component' (length=9)
      public 'level' => string '2' (length=1)
      public 'language' => string '*' (length=1)
      public 'browserNav' => string '0' (length=1)
      public 'access' => string '1' (length=1)
      protected 'params' => 
          object(Joomla\Registry\Registry)[1491]
          protected 'data' => 
              object(stdClass)[1494]
              ...
              protected 'initialized' => boolean true
              public 'separator' => string '.' (length=1)
              public 'home' => string '0' (length=1)
              public 'img' => string ' ' (length=1)
              public 'template_style_id' => string '0' (length=1)
              public 'component_id' => string '22' (length=2)
              public 'parent_id' => string '122' (length=3)
              public 'component' => string 'com_content' (length=11)
              public 'tree' => 
                  array (size=2)
                  0 => string '122' (length=3)
                  1 => string '1545' (length=4)
                  public 'query' => 
                      array (size=3)
                      'option' => string 'com_content' (length=11)
                      'view' => string 'article' (length=7)
                      'id' => string '262' (length=3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm correctly understanding what you're wanting to do, this code doesn't do it. I *think* you're wanting $hasNestedNav to be true when the active menu item has children, and what it's doing is actually setting $hasNestedNav true always (every menu item has a parent, the root items in every menu will have parent_id == 1).

If what you're wanting is a test for the existence of children of the current item, try this:

```
$menu = JFactory::getApplication()->getMenu()
$active = $menu->getActive();
$childCount = count($menu->getItems('parent_id', $active->id);
```

And then test $childCount to see if there are children of the active menu item. (Interesting side note: the return from the getItems call is an array of the child menu items, so you could stuff that into a variable if you wanted to do any further checking or filtering -- for example walking the array to filter out the menu items that have the parameter menu_show set to off (hides them from navigation menus) to keep them from counting towards the total.)

Obviously, this code isn't testing for the Bad Stuff that could happen if any of those calls fail, it's just the 'happy path' to the answer. I'll leave the error handling as an exercise for the reader.

### Filtering

```
$children = $menu->getItems('parent_id', $active->id);
$visibleChildren = array_filter($children, function($child) {
    $params = $child->getParams();
    return ($params->get('menu_show', 1) === 1);
});
```

After which the array $visibleChildren will contain only the ones with "menu_show" set to 1. You can then count it to know if there are visible children.

Or, if this doesn't work on your version of PHP (or if it just seems like too much work) you could simply walk the $children array with a foreach and test each child's "menu_show" param, breaking out of the loop on the first occurrence of a "true" (after all, for your purposes how many there are doesn't matter, all you need to know is there is at least one visible child).

Comment: Thanks for the code. It has got me most of the way. Now I need to check to see if any of the children menu items have the "Display in menu" parameter set to "No". Would I need to grab that param and perform a second check?

Comment: Probably the simplest way to do that is to pass the getItems() array into array_filter(). That way you can test the param in the callback, and the resulting array will have only the visible items left in it.

Comment: Thanks for the code. I have implemented it in my template and have modified `$childCount = count($menu->getItems('parent_id', $active->id));` to be `$childCount = count($visibleChildren);`. When I use `var_dump($childCount)`, the value is always **0** even if there are a mix of **Display in Menu** menu items. Using PHP 7.3.9.

Comment: The result from the call to getActive drives that, so which menu item is returned from it? The other important value is what the parent_id is: $active->parent_id, because what this code is doing is getting all the menu items with that parent_id (Libraries/src/Menu/SiteMenu.php). Things that can effect this include various SEF add-ons.

Comment: Nothing is being returned. Outputting a `var_dump` in the browser using `$visibleChildren` displays an empty array. I have updated my original question with the code that you suggested and am currently using.

Comment: Well then, let's take a step back and see what $active is and what $children is. I'm suspecting, from what you're saying, that $children will also be empty array, and if so it becomes interesting what $active will say.

Comment: I have added the `var_dump` output of `$active` and `$children` to my original question. In the case of `$active`, the menu item is the parent, and for `$children`, the output are the children of the `$active` menu item.

Comment: ARRRGGGH! Mea Culpa. I left out a step. I don't know why I kept staring at it and didn't see it, instead of focusing on why my code worked on my setup and not yours. Sigh. I'll blame it on getting old. Yeah, that's my story and I'm sticking to it! getParams gets the Registry object, then get() gets the value for the param from the registry. I'll edit my code above. The change is the lines in the filter function.

Comment: Thank you very much for your assistance. I have implemented your code and it is working just as needed.

Comment: Update to my previous comment: I have implemented your code and it is working almost as needed. The problem now lies when visiting the children pages.  The `$childCount` returns to **0**, which causes the **boolean** to return **false**. It needs to remain **true** whether the parent or children items are active.

Comment: There's a variable named "tree" in the menu item. It's an array of all the parents of this particular menu item. I'm losing the thread of this, now, so I'm not 100% sure I understand what you're needing, but I think you can use that array to walk back up the menu tree to see if it should be active.

Comment: Thanks for the "tree" tip. I will test it out and see how it goes.

Comment: $active->tree will have its parent's ids in it, but picking out which of those id's should be showing menus in any given spot might be a bit dicey, that's where I started to lose the thread of what you're trying to do. I thought you were only concerned about 2 menu levels.

Comment: I am only wanting to have the nested nav displayed when on the parent and next level children pages. The menu is only two levels deep.

Comment: I am currently using this workaround `$parent = $active->parent_id;` and `if ($childCount > 1 || $parent > 1) { $hasNestedNav = true; }`. It is working, but it may not be the most appropriate way of checking.

Comment: Looks as good a mechanism as any. Glad I could help.